# FileZilla will not start on Slackware

Tags: ftp, slackware, filezilla

I think it was because I tried to install. Slackware txz 13 and mine is 14.1 64 bit, but I do not know where baicho package for Slack 14.1 can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile from source (according to wiki https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Client_Compile ):

Install dependencies:

```
wxWidgets
GnuTLS
libidn
gettext (Compiletime only)
libdbus (under Unix-like systems)
```

Download source package:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla_Client/3.7.4.1/FileZilla_3.7.4.1_src.tar.bz2/download

Exact source archive:

```
tar -xvf File-name.tar.bz2
```

Enter exacted directory and compile:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

That's all.

Comment: I installed the dependencies but gave an error when making the make command .

             ^
make[3]: *** [libengine_a-ControlSocket.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/patterson/Downloads/filezilla-3.7.4.1/src/engine'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/patterson/Downloads/filezilla-3.7.4.1/src/engine'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/patterson/Downloads/filezilla-3.7.4.1/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
bash-4.2#

Comment: What error? Describe it. Do you have gcc?

Comment: Which version of wxWidgets are you using? Filezilla requires wxWidgets>=2.8.4.

Answer (score 3):

The SlackBuild makes it pretty easy: http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.1/network/filezilla/

There is one required dependency, wxPython, which also has a SlackBuild: http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.1/libraries/wxPython/

Download the source, [wxPython-src-2.8.12.1.tar.bz2](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1.tar.bz2) and the SlackBuild, [wxPython.tar.gz](http://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/14.1/libraries/wxPython.tar.gz).

From wherever you downloaded them to,

```
# tar xzf wxPython.tar.gz 
# mv wxPython-src-2.8.12.1.tar.bz2 wxPython
# cd wxPython
# ./wxPython.SlackBuild
```

It'll build the package, and at the end it'll tell you something like,

```
Slackware package /tmp/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1-x86_64-1_SBo.tgz created.
```

Install the package:

```
# installpkg /tmp/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1-x86_64-1_SBo.tgz
```

Now that the dependency is installed, you repeat the process with FileZilla. Download the source, [FileZilla_3.7.4_src.tar.bz2](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/filezilla/FileZilla_3.7.4_src.tar.bz2) and the SlackBuild, [filezilla.tar.gz](http://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/14.1/network/filezilla.tar.gz).

From wherever you downloaded them to,

```
# tar xzf filezilla.tar.gz 
# mv FileZilla_3.7.4_src.tar.bz2 filezilla
# cd filezilla
# ./filezilla.SlackBuild
```

It'll build the package, and at the end it'll tell you something like,

```
Slackware package /tmp/FileZilla_3.7.4-x86_64-1_SBo.tgz created.
```

Install the package:

```
# installpkg /tmp/FileZilla_3.7.4-x86_64-1_SBo.tgz
```

That's it! Now you can run FileZilla.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped me! I installed filezilla with your help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!